# Get most recent file in S3 via PySpark

Tags: apache-spark, amazon-s3, pyspark

Is there anyway to get the last file in an S3 repo via Pyspark?

I managed to do it with Python using this code:

```
paginator = client.get_paginator('list_objects_v2')
pages = paginator.paginate(Bucket=Bucket, Prefix=Path)
for page in pages:
   for obj in page['Contents']:
       latest = max(page['Contents'], key=lambda x: x['LastModified'])
```

And on Spark i can't find any documentation.

Thank you

Comment: That boto3 code should work fine in the spark environment too, is there a reason you can't use it as-is?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you'd just use the Hadoop FileSystem APIs, use listStatusIterator()/listFiles() to get an iterator and scan, `FileStatus.getModificationTime()` gives you that last modified field.

Be aware though: S3 timestamp of large file uploads is time upload was started, not completed. A large file which took many minutes to upload would appear older than a small file uploaded in a single PUT which took place during the upload.